# Como desabilito dois botoes ao mesmo tempo? ANGULAR

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Eu tenho dois botoes que o ID deles vem de um dado do banco de dados:

```
<tr *ngFor="let dads of DadosOs">
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success but" id="{{dads.NUMOS}}  - A" value = "{{dads.CODPROD}} - {{dads.ITEM}}"
            #ref (click)="BaixaOkey(ref.id, ref.value)">SIM</button></td>
        <!-- ! -->
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger but" id="{{dads.CODPROD}} - {{dads.ITEM}} " value="{{dads.NUMOS}}"
            #ref2 (click)="not(ref2.id, ref2.value)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalNao">NÃO</button></td>
        <!-- ! -->
        <td>{{dads.ITEM}}</td>
        <td>{{dads.CODPROD}} - {{dads.PRODUTO}}</td>
  </tr>
```

E no TS eu tento desabilitar assim:

```
(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(id)).disabled = true;
```

Mas aí só desabilita o botão 'SIM' mas eu preciso que desabilite o botão 'NÃO' também.

Tem alguma forma de desabilitar os dois botões ao mesmo tempo sem ser pelo ID?

Comment: Um id é como CPF, cada um tem o seu.

Comment: Eu sei disso, mas não tem outra forma de desabilitar os dois botões sem ser pelo id?

Comment: Acho que pode pela classe. Veja se isso funciona: `(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementsByClassName('but')[0]).disabled = true;`

Comment: Não funciona pra mim pq ai ele ta amarrado ao [0], e pode vim uns 10 botoes, ai só pode desabilitar aquele sim e nao da td que foi clicado

Answer (score 0):

Da uma olhadinha se isso te ajuda

ts:

```
const desabilitarBotoes = false;

export class Classe {

    metodoNoMeioDoCodigo() {
        if (algumaCoisa) {
            this.desabilitarBotoes = true;
        }
    }

}
```

html:

```
<button id="botao1" class="" (click)="clickBotao1()" [disabled]="desabilitarBotoes">
<button id="botao2" class="" (click)="clickBotao2()" [disabled]="desabilitarBotoes">
```

Ou ainda, pra ficar sempre verificando se desabilita ou não utilize:

```
public get desabilitarBotoes() {
    return algumaCoisa;
}
```

Comment: e o 'algumaCoisa' seria o q?

Comment: seria uma variável/função/expressão booleana de sua preferencia, nomeei "algumaCoisa"